# PHP: How to select and display from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have two tables in my database. One labeled with tempahanbilik and the other one is bilik. Both tables have a column named id (which hold the same value). Now, i want to display the other data that is not in tempahanbilik's table

Below is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tempahanbilik 
        WHERE tarikh BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['tarikh']."' AND '".$_SESSION['tarikh2']."'
    && tempahanbilik.id NOT IN (SELECT bilik.id FROM bilik)";


$results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);




$q = "SELECT * FROM bilik";



$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);

   $total = $results->num_rows;
    if($total>0)
    {
        while($rows=$results->fetch_assoc())
        {   

            $nama = $rows['tempat'];
             echo" <tr>
         <td align = center><a href='tengokKosong2.php?tempat=$nama'>$nama</a></td>";

         echo "</tr>";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        { 

            $id=$row['id'];
            $nama =$row['nama'];

         echo" <tr>
         <td align = center><a href='tengokKosong2.php?id=$id&nama=$nama'>$nama</a></td>";

         echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Search for "JOINS" in sql

Comment: You need JOINS as @Rajnish say. and your tables have to have unique keys and references to other table to join them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display the info from bilik that is not in tempahanbilik right?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM bilik 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tempahanbilik WHERE 
tarikh BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['tarikh']."' AND '".$_SESSION['tarikh2']."')";
```

Please try using the above query and let me know it have result or not..

Comment: Yessss!  I've got the result ! TQSM for helping @Firdaus Shukor

Answer (score 0):

No need to join tables, you can use `sub query`. your query should be like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tempahanbilik 
    WHERE ( tarikh BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['tarikh']."' AND '".$_SESSION['tarikh2']."'
) AND tempahanbilik.id NOT IN (SELECT bilik.id FROM bilik)";
```

Comment: that is a way too

Comment: Sorry, it still returns a blank page :(

Comment: post your table's structure.